# script to start service from status check

Tags: bash, shell, centos

I have an app on Centos that daily shuts down. Until I can get the support on it, I would like to handle it from a script in order when this occur again. My current script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if /path/to/service_check status service | grep -q 'SHUTDOWN'; then
        /path/to/service_check start service
fi
```

It is setup in crontab to run on one minute interval but it is not running correctly. Is this approach incorrect?

Thank you!

Comment: If you run the script from the command line, does it run correctly?

Comment: Have a run through the troubleshooting tips from the [Stack Overflow `crontab` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info).  Generally, this type of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your basic approach, assuming that `service_check` returns a string you can `grep` (though very often, these scripts set an exit code, so that you can use them directly in an `if` condition).

Answer (score 0):

1. check crond services is running `systemctl  status crond`
2. check your script`s privilage `chmod +x  scriptname.sh`
3. execute the script manually on the terminal  `/path/to/your/scriptname.sh`
4. check your crontab configure,you should set the user to run this script `*  *  *  *  * root  /path/to/your/scriptname.sh`